# Change whitespace to underscore at specific positions

Tags: python, regex

I have string like this:

```
strings = ['pic1.jpg siberian cat 24 25', 'pic2.jpg siemese cat 14 32', 'pic3.jpg american bobtail cat 8 13', 'pic4.jpg cat 9 1']
```

What I want is to replace whitespace between cat breeds to hyphen eliminating whitespace between .jpg and first word in breed, and numbers.

Expected output:

```
['pic1.jpg siberian_cat 24 25', 'pic2.jpg siemese_cat 14 32', 'pic3.jpg american_bobtail cat 8 13', 'pic4.jpg cat 9 1']
```

I tried to construct patterns as follows:

```
[re.sub(r'(?<!jpg\s)([a-z])\s([a-z])\s([a-z])', r'\1_\2_\3', x) for x in strings ]
```

However, I adds hyphen between .jpg and next word.

The problem is that "cat" is not always put at the end of the word combination.

Comment: is keyword "cat" always going to be present inside your string?

Comment: @Anonymous actually not. there can be any world at the end. Even only "american bobtail" string can occur. The only thing that will always "stable" is '.jpg' and numbers at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach using `re.sub` with a callback function:

```py
strings = ['pic1.jpg siberian cat 24 25', 'pic2.jpg siemese cat 14 32', 'pic3.jpg american bobtail cat 8 13', 'pic4.jpg cat 9 1']  
output = [re.sub(r'(?<!\S)\w+(?: \w+)* cat\b', lambda x: x.group().replace(' ', '_'), x) for x in strings]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
['pic1.jpg siberian_cat 24 25',
 'pic2.jpg siemese_cat 14 32',
 'pic3.jpg american_bobtail_cat 8 13',
 'pic4.jpg cat 9 1']
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern used:

```regex
(?<!\S)    assert what precedes first word is either whitespace or start of string
\w+        match a word, which is then followed by
(?: \w+)*  a space another word, zero or more times
[ ]        match a single space
cat\b      followed by 'cat'
```

In other words, taking the third list element as an example, the regex pattern matches `american bobtail cat`, then replaces all spaces by underscore in the lambda callback function.

Comment: Had to be more precise, sorry. Cat is not always in the end. However, in third string we do not have underscore between american and bobtail as expected

Comment: @Ison I have updated my answer using `re.sub` with a callback function.

Comment: As I've said, the problem is that "cat" is not always in the end position hence if I delete it from pattern the code wont work, thats why I tried to stuck to avoiding whitespace change after .jpg =(

Comment: I have answered the question you asked above.

Comment: run the code above with strings = ['pic1.jpg siberian husky 24 25', 'pic2.jpg siemese cat 14 32', 'pic3.jpg american bobtail cat 8 13', 'pic4.jpg cat 9 1'] and it wont add _ between siberian husky. Thats why Im pointing that cat is not the only possible ending. But the .jpg will always be before breed

Comment: changed your pattern to r'(?<!\S)\w+(?: \w+)* [a-zA-Z]|cat\b'

Comment: @Ison For a more specific regex, if you know the full list of animals, just use an alternation instead of `cat`: `(?:cat|dog|fox|...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this `[re.sub(r'jpg\s((\S+\s)+)cat', "jpg " + "_".join(x.split('jpg')[1].split('cat')[0].strip().split()) + "_cat", x) for x in strings ]`